# How $W^{\pm}$ bosons get their electric charge $\pm 1$ as opposed to $Z_0$ that have neutral electric charge?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, electroweak, leptons

In the 'Standard Model' book by Y. Grossman and Y. Nir, in chapter 7 (the leptonic standard model) on page 93 after defining the charge of the broken symmetry generator, i.e $Q=T_3+Y$

they say that
the $W_{\mu}^{\pm}$ are eigenstates of $T_{3}$ with eigenvalues $\pm1$, and have Y = 0. Hence, their electromagnetic charges are: $q(W_{\mu}^+
 ) = +1; q(W_{\mu}^{-} ) = -1$

Both $W_{3\mu}$ and $B_{\mu}$ are eigenstates of $T_3$ with eigenvalue 0, and have Y = 0. Hence, they are
neutral under $U(1)_{EM}$ and so is any linear combination of them:
$q(Z^0_{\mu}) = 0; q(A^0_{\mu}) = 0$

My question is how they found those eigenvalues.
What are the matrices represent $W_{\mu}^{\pm}$,$W_{3\mu}$ and $B_{\mu}$ I need to diagonalise and find those values?

Comment: Write down the weak isotriplet of the *W* s, the three *T*  generators of SU(2) in the triplet representation, and see how these three matrices act on your triplet. As an isosinglet, $B_\mu $ is defined to be a number not acted upon by these matrices. You may represent *Y* as the 3x3 identity matrix.